# lib commonCrypto not available for iOS simulator?

Tags: iphone, ios, simulator, commoncrypto

I've been adding libCommonCrypto.dylib to my project to do md5 hash verification. Works all proper on the iPhone (iOS 5.1), but when I try to run it on the simulator, I get this error:

```
ld: library not found for -lcommonCrypto
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I'm a bit clueless why this happens. I added the commonCrypto to the project target -> build phase -> link binary with libraries. Is there any additional step required to get it working also in the simulator?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You don't have to add that dynamic library. It is available by default in

> iphoneOS >> usr/include

and

> iphoneSimulator >> usr/include

Comment: Doh! Yes, that solved it. I thought I had to add it. Thanks for the quick help, greatly appreciated.

Comment: @MartinSchultz. Glad to be of some help :)

Comment: @Vignesh hi! can you explain a little bit more please? i have the same problem but with your answer i don't really know what to do...thanks

Comment: @Pach, My answer says you don't have to add the library explicitly. It is available by default. If you have added it, remove it.

Comment: Thanks vignesh.it was a great help.