# Common Crypto Library error

Tags: iphone, ios, md5

I am trying to convert NSString to MD5 Hash. I have used this algorithm [MD5 algorithm in Objective C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1524604/md5-algorithm-in-objective-c)

While running the program I am getting following error

```
ld: library not found for -lcommonCrypto
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Can anyone tell me what I am missing here?

I have also added libcommonCrypto.dylib

Comment: Please remove it and add it again to your code

Comment: Added it again, closed the Xcode opened it again, tried many things but the error won't go :(

Comment: Glad for finiding answer

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9839193/lib-commoncrypto-not-available-for-ios-simulator

Answer (score 2):

Just remove the library from Build Phase -> Link Binary with Libraries. It would resolve the issue